# How to interpret a specific value

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interpretation

We need to make a prediction on a data set; we will use logistic regression.

We have the following predictor variable: `spezialiserung_schule` (specialisation school); it is nominal and can take the values "art", "science" and "trade".

If we run a simple logistic regression on it and check the results using `summary()`, we get the results shown below.

We are particularly interested in the estimate and the p-value. We understand that for both values p is quite large and the estimates are not great either.

If it were a simple binary variable I could multiply the estimate by 0 or 1 and then add the intercept and get the log(ratio). How exactly do I evaluate this if I am no longer using binary? What would be the next step that I take afterwards?

```r
glm(formula = job ~ (spezialisierung_schule), 
    family = binomial("logit"), data = Trainingsdaten)
```

Deviance Residuals

| Min | 1Q | Mean | 2Q | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1.5786 | -1.5392 | 0.8237 | 0.8545 | 1.3018 |

Coefficients

|  | Estimate | Std. Error | z value | Pr(>IzI) |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 0.81944 | 0.23539 | 3.481 | 0.000499 | *** |
| spezialisierung_schuleKunst | -1.10712 | 0.79921 | -1.385 | 0.165972 |  |
| spezialisierung_schuleWissenschaft | 0.08728 | 0.34966 | 0.250 | 0.802884 |  |

Comment: Hey Ben, precisely. My goal in the end is to understand how to handle this kind of variable in a logistic regression and to understand the impact of the coefficients.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "using binary"?

Comment: Sure :) A binary variable would be men vs female, which could be coded to 0 or 1. So i could calculate with the estimate something like intercept + estimate x 0 if it is a female or intercept + estimate x 1 if it is a male. For instance to calculate if a male is more likely to have a heart attack than a female.
I got that from StatQuest: https://youtu.be/C4N3_XJJ-jU?t=506

Comment: It's better practice to include your summary output as cut-and-pasted text rather than an image (among other things, an image is inaccessible to anyone using a screen reader). For this case you probably only need the first line (the `glm()` call) and the coefficient table ...

Comment: I updated the post. I'm still trying to learn the stack rules/best practices.